# Conditional templates in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a login page, which is just a simple form in the center of the page with no header, footer or sidebar. My regular pages will have a sidebar, header and footer (these 3 are directives). I call all my templates in `ng-view`, depending on the routes.
I want to place my directives outside `ng-view` since they'll be common across all the pages except login and I don't want them to be fetched on every URL change.

How do I have a login page without the 3 directives?

Comment: what do you mean by "call it" in the ng-view?

Comment: As in view it! I mean when the `/login` route is hit, the login form should be loaded in `ng-view`.

Comment: Ah, so you want to take directives that are currently inside of your login ng-view, and put  it outside of it. Sounds like a good plan, what issues are you having?

Comment: I want them to be hidden when I'm on the login page! But don't know the proper way to do it!

Comment: Personally, I would redirect to another page rather than show/hide components off of a login page. But its up to you. If you want to show  hide components on a login page, you can bind elements using ng-show/ng-hide based on a persistent variable like an auth cookie, that is set server-side.

Comment: I hesitate to give this as an answer, because there is probably a sensible way to do it with built-in angular routing.
Still using angular-ui-router this would be very easy: Have a top level state, one child state for the login page and another child state with the sidebar/header/footer layout which is the parent of all other "regular" (logged-in) states.

Comment: I may be on the right track with what the op is looking for (or I may be completely out to lunch).  Anyways, check this out: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: @StephenFriedrich Reached ui.router via some other resource! So my parent state will be a blank page, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [a small plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UnrIl08BWXGtY1QiFAHq?p=preview) to offer you a solution to your issue.

this is the base of the solution:

```
<ng-include src="appVm.templatetoShow">
</ng-include>
```

in the Appcontroller :

```
  function AppController() {
     this.templatetoShow = 'login.html';
  }
```

I included a couple of templates that gets loaded when needed.

After some rereading, I made [a new plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpc4nPJArfCm84mbQVRb?p=preview) to show you how this can be done.
The hiding part is simple, just add some CSS into the mix, and you won't see
anything from your main page. 
Added some cloaking to prevent FOUC, and wrote a couple of lines to show
an authentication system. 
I introduced an User service that you can inject wherever you need the users
data.

Is this more in what you wanted?

Comment: Good example, but it loads the page on clicking the log in button and not after authentication!

Comment: @Rutwick, I showed a way how to implement the system for showing/hiding a (login) dialog separate from a normal ng-view. The op knew hot to do the log in, so I didn't repeat that.

Comment: :) oh, Now I noticed, @RutwickGangurde, you _are_ the op! :)
do you want me to add the login form to the sample?

Comment: Yes! That would be great :)

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, I wrote a new plunk to show you how your problem might be solved!

Comment: The new example looks better. Let me please check it!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, just curious, did you check out the example? Have any questions left?

Comment: I ended up using `ui.router` and creating separate states for login and dashboard. But your example helped me a lot! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I get what You really want to do, but i would suggest to use ng-if

such ng-if may look look like this:

```
<div ng-if="notLogin"> here is Your navbar contents. Directies, anything You need </div>
```

and then in controller -

```
$scope.notLogin = $location.path() !== "/login"
```

If You have directives for footers, navbars etc, i think You can do that in directive controller and hide all content of directive there, so directive will be empty.

You may also use global controller to do that job and wrap those directives in divs like in my example. Doing it in directives looks cleaner though.

Hope its what You need.

Comment: I tried this already, but the directive is already compiled when the login page loads, hence the condition stays true on all the pages and the directives stay hidden!

Comment: Oh right! So the workaround is to wrap directives in divs like i showed You in example. Then directive will stay out of template if global controller catch another path another then /login. Angualar have all those precompile, compile options to use, but im not familiar with them. sorry.

Comment: NO problem! :) I'm trying something with ui.router!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-if` to conditionally display/hide them on UI. Please note that `ng-if` is different than `ng-switch`. The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM.

```
More details - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf
```

Qucik Steps -

1. create a shell page and set the header, footer, sidebar and a view
2. use `ng-if={{User.isLoggedin}}` for header, footer, sidebar and login
3. set `User.isLoggedin` to false when user is not logged in
4. Set it to true once user loged in

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that! But it sounds very jQueryish, and I'm trying to be a bit more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Directives are shared across all views if you use the **same controller** however using different controllers is not adviced either. what makes you uncomfortable with that ?

have a look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213055/1218551

best wishes:)