# Unable to Pass data between two views from one controller in AngularJS app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 views. View1 and View2.  View1 has list of products and checkboxes next to it and submit button. View2 is the page that displays the products selected from view1. My goal is to send the products selected (using checkboxes) from view1 to view2.

Here is my code..

```
 **<a href="/#/Details/{{cartprd}}" class="bg-white" ng-click="SendToCartPage(cartprd)">{{fff}}</a>**

 <tr>
     <td>
       **<input type="checkbox" ng-click="UpdateCart(tbl, $event)" ng-bind="tbl" id=" {{$index + 1}} " />**
     </td>
     <td>
       <div>
            <div class="thumbnail" ng-mouseover="getproductonhover()">
               <div class="caption">
                  <span class="">{{tbl.ProdName}}</span>
                  <p class="">{{tbl.ProdDescription}}</p>
               </div>
                  <img src="~/Images/imgcamera.jpg" class="imgproduct" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{tbl.ProdName}}</td>
      <td>{{tbl.ProdDescription}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="GetSingleProduct(tbl)">Edit</a>
        </td>
  </tr>
```

Controller.js

```
app.controller('CartController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.SendToCartPage = function (cartprd) {       
    return cartprd;
}
});
```

View2

```
<div ng-controller="CartController">
{{SendToCartPage}} 
</div>
```

I see an empty page in the view2. Can someone please tell me what mistake I am doing? One thing I noticed is when I make `$scope.SendToCartPage = "mystring"` then I can see `"mystring"` in view2.

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: use `ngInit` to pass the parameters

Comment: I am using MVC views. Sorry, I cannot create a plunker for this. I am looking for quick answers.

Comment: ngInit ?? how ? What's wrong in my method?

Comment: @user3501278 can you not use angularjs service?

Comment: I am new to Angular. I don't know how to use it but I am not understanding what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @user3501278 see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this goal you can use angularjs [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) which helps to organize and share code across your app.

So create a basic service like this

```
var appmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);
appmodule.factory('myService', function() {
 var savedCheckedData = {}
 function setData(data) {
   savedCheckedData = data;
 }
 function getData() {
  return savedCheckedData;
 }    
 return {
  set: setData,
  get: getData
 }    
});
```

So now inject this service in controller.When in `view1` you select checkbox push the selected data using `setData`.And in `View2` get the data using `getData` and display it.

So actually your code would look like this

```
app.controller('CartController', function ($scope, $routeParams, myService)
{
  $scope.SendToCartPage = function (cartprd) {       
    //get the checkboxes data here and push it        
    myService.set(cartprd);
}
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: 'sharedData' is undefined

Comment: actually you dont need additional scope variable.Now see and try

Comment: No luck buddy. This doesn't work.                              $scope.SendToCartPage = function (cartprd) {       
  
        myService.set(cartprd)
    }

Comment: you are doing something wrong.what is cartprd?I said you should get the checked objects and set it to set function of service.

Comment: cartprd is the checked objects.

Comment: so what happens ?data is not getting saved in service object?any error in console? are you not able to use myService.get() in other view?

Comment: Yahoo !! It's working. I used get() in another view using ngInit event. That worked like a charm.  Am I doing the right method?

Comment: Thanks Neel. You are a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that `SendToCartPage` is a function rather than a value. So in View2, when you tell it to display `SendToCartPage`, you are not passing it any arguments and therefore not getting any result back.

You could modify SendToCartPage to instead store the argument in a scope variable, like so:

```
$scope.SendToCartPage = function (cartprd) {       
    $scope.cartContents = cartprd;
}
```

Then you'd modify your View2 code to look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="CartController">
    {{cartContents}} 
</div>
```

I assume you probably want your cart contents to be able to contain several things. In that case, you can modify your function so that `cartContents` is an array instead (adding the argument to the array each time it is called), and you can use `ng-repeat` in your view to display each item in the array.

Comment: Yeah, I believe @Neel has a more complete answer to your question. If you have two views associated with two different controllers (each view should have its own controller), then the best way to share data between them is with a service.

Comment: I have only one controller not two.

Comment: I'd recommend having a separate controller for each view, as this is the best practice, and you can have issues when sharing a controller across different views (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213055/4797998) for more details).